# Can the logical equivalence of two different statements to the same proposition imply that the three of them are false?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let$\ P_0 $be our original proposition and$\ P_1 :a<b $ and$\ P_2:a<c $ the statements that are equivalent to$\ P_0 $. Now, if it is known that$\ b<c $, then there is an interval of values of$\ x $ such that$\ b<x<c $. Since both$\ P_1 $ and$\ P_2 $ are necessary and sufficient for the truth of$\ P_0 $, doesn't it mean that for the latter to be true it is only needed that$\ a $ assumes *any* value respectively$\ <b $ and$\ <c $, and we can't just say that$\ a$ must be$\ <b $? If so, recall $\ b<x<c $. If$\ a $ is in this interval, then$\ P_1 $ is false and $\ P_2 $ is true, leading to the contradictory result that $\ P_0 $ is at the same time true and false. Thus, may we conclude that$\ P_0 $ is false?

I hope I made myself clear.

EDIT: I'm putting here some more details from my answer to Nick and paw88789.
what I'm saying is that, known that $\ P_2 $ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\ P_0 $, one should be able to pick *any* $\ x<c $ for $\ P_0 $ to be true. But, as it turns out, it's not like that. In fact, if $\ b<a<c $ we have that $\ P_0 $ is both true and false, which is a contradiction, so they're all false.
Alternatively, we may note that it must be $\ a<b  $ to avoid the "contradictory interval". Thus, $\ P_2 $ loses its sufficiency, which is absurd since it was demonstrated. 
This is why I *thought of concluding* that all the propositions are false.

My latest guess is that since both $\ P_1 $ and $\ P_2 $ have been proven to be equivalent to$\ P_0 $, the truth of either of the three statements implies that of the others, and that's exactly because $\ a $ can't lie in the "contradictory interval", so showing that$\ a <c $ gives us that$\ a <b $ as well. That is, we can't deduce the falsity of the three statements.

Comment: What is this original proposition $P_0$? Are you sure that it really is equivalent to both $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: @Adriano It is an exercise that I came up with after bumping into a completely similar situation, days ago. So I can't really remember what$\ P_0 $ dealt with, but it definitely wasn't something a priori related to $\ P_1 $ and $\ P_2 $, so that doesn't really matter. I remember that its equivalence to both $\ P_1 $ and $\ P_2 $ was rigorously proved.

Comment: If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are logically equivalent and necessary (and sufficient) conditions for $P_0$ to be true, then proving one false should be enough to prove $P_0$ false, I think. This is just my intuition - I can't prove this formally.  More or less...I think I agree with you.

Comment: @mathtastic Your intuition is correct, but I'm not talking about that. I've made it clearer in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a proposition $P_0$ and you say it is equivalent to $P_1:a<b$ and it is also equivalent to $P_2: a<c$. You say you also know $b<c$ and I assume they are all real numbers. This is not enough to conclude that these statements cannot all be true together, e.g. $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$ satisfies these conditions. It's different if $a$ is a free variable:

Let's look at $$S_1=\{a|a<b\}, S_2=\{a|a<c\}.$$ We know $S_1=S_2$ because $P_1$ is equivalent to $P_2$. We also know $\frac{b+c}{2}\in S_2\setminus S_1$ because $b<\frac{b+c}{2}<c$. We therefore have arrived at a contradiction. **If** you were attempting to do a proof by contradiction, assuming $P_1$ or $P_2$, knowing that $b<c$ and that $P_1$ is equivalent to $P_2$, then yes you can conclude that all of $P_0, P_1, P_2$ are false. Otherwise, you have derived a contradiction, hopefully a mistake or misunderstanding somewhere, otherwise we are all in trouble...

Comment: actually, $b\in S_2\setminus S_1$ if $b<c$, no need for $\frac{b+c}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Nick had given an answer and it looks like it was deleted, I'm sorry if it was me, I didn't do it on purpose. He had pointed out that $\ P_1 $ and $\ P_2 $ must be equivalent as well, thus, the three statements can't be true.

Yeah, in general I would agree with him. The fact is that$\ P_1$ and$\ P_2 $ are inequalities, and it was perfectly clear that $\ b \neq c $. I know, what Nick said should always hold, yet I'm sure those inequalities were not the same...
Anyway, what I'm saying is that, known that $\ P_2 $ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\ P_0 $, one should be able to pick *any* $\ x<c $ for $\ P_0 $ to be true. But, as it turns out, it's not like that. In fact, if $\ b<a<c $ we have that $\ P_0 $ is both true and false, which is a contradiction, so they're all false.
Alternatively, we may note that it must be $\ a<b  $ to avoid the "contradictory interval". Thus, $\ P_2 $ loses its sufficiency, which is absurd since it was demonstrated. 
This is why I would conclude that all the propositions are false.

Answer (score 0):

One way out of your predicament would be if $a$ had to be an integer while $b$, $c$ were reals.  Then for instance we could have:

$P_0: a<2$

$P_1:a<1.8$; and

$P_2:a<1.9$

These would be consistent with your problem (since $a$ is to be an integer).  That is, for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $P_0$ is logically equivalent to both $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: Yes,$\ a $ is a natural number whereas$\ b $ and$\ c $ are positive real numbers, but as I said in a comment,$\ P_0 $ is not an inequality. And this isn't an impossible imaginary situation because I bumped into it days ago, reading through various stuff, though I forgot about the specific context.
My guess is that since both $\ P_1 $ and $\ P_2 $ have been proven to be equivalent to$\ P_0 $, the truth of either of the three statements implies that of the others, and that's exactly because $\ a $ can't lie in the "contradictory interval", so showing that$\ a <c $ gives us that$\ a <b $ as well.

Comment: That is, we can't deduce the falsity of the three statements.